# Symfony 2 ParamConverter Not Working

Tags: php, symfony

I want to use the ParamConverter in symfony2 but i keeps return exceptions.

I have this code :

```
/**
 * @Route("/")
 * @Route("/{_locale}")
 * @ParamConverter("domain", class="ProdacomMainBundle:PdbDomain")
 * @Template("ProdacomMainBundle:Main:index.html.twig, vars={"domain"})
 */
public function indexAction(PdbDomain $domain) {

}
```

The error it keeps returning :

```
    FileLoaderLoadException: Cannot import resource "C:\htdocs\domeinbeheer\src\Prodacom\MainBundle/Controller/" from "C:/htdocs/domeinbeheer/app/config\routing.yml". ([Syntax Error] Expected Doctrine\Common\Annotations\DocLexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS, got 'domain' at position 177 in method Prodacom\MainBundle\Controller\MainController::indexAction().)
```

And this one :

```
    AnnotationException: [Syntax Error] Expected Doctrine\Common\Annotations\DocLexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS, got 'domain' at position 177 in method Prodacom\MainBundle\Controller\MainController::indexAction().
```

Any ideas ?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed an ending quote here:

```
 @Template("ProdacomMainBundle:Main:index.html.twig, vars={"domain"})
                                                   ^
```

That's what both of those exceptions are saying.

But if you fix those you'll see that $domain cannot be populated unless you have a GET/POST parameter named `domain` supplying the ID.

Also if you want the `domain` parameter to be optional then you'll have to define your index action like this:

```
public function indexAction(PdbDomain $domain = null)
```

Otherwise you'll receive some new exceptions saying that $domain cannot be null.

Answer (score -1):

Oke after reading the documentation again http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html

The ParamConverter only seems to work with request paramaters in the url for example a {id} parameter in the route.

It converts the {id} parameter to a object so it is required to have something like this in the route.